# HttpWebRequest one url, two target ip

Tags: c#, .net

I must individually test each server of a cluster. Each server have one IP address but I must use same URL. I am using a console project.

```
static string RequestGet(string requestUrl, string ipspecify)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(requestUrl);

    // Submit the request, and get the response body.
    string responseBodyFromRemoteServer;
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
       
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseBodyFromRemoteServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return responseBodyFromRemoteServer;
}
```

Locally, I can modify my host file, but I want to do this automatically through my program.

```
RequestGet("https://toto.org/myservice", "172.2.240.16")
RequestGet("https://toto.org/myservice", "172.2.240.17")
```

IP address is server address.

What is the solution?

Comment: An IP address can directly be part of a URL. You're not required to use the domain name - although it can cause a problem with SSL certificates if you don't, so you might come unstuck on that. The only way I can think of really would be to take one of the servers out of the cluster do you know for sure you're targeting the other one. Without addressing the request directly to the IP of one machine, your client cannot control which of the servers responds - that's down to the cluster software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out, as of .NET 5, this is possible using `HttpClient`. `SocketsHttpHandler`, the default handler used by `HttpClient`, gained a [`ConnectCallback` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler.connectcallback?view=net-5.0) which lets you override how a connection to the remote machine is established.

[Here's where it's called](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Http/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs,1275), which you can use as inspiration for writing your own. The following seems to work fine:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    using var client = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler() { ConnectCallback = ConnectCallback });
    
    await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com");
}

private static async ValueTask<Stream> ConnectCallback(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var endPoint = new DnsEndPoint("1.2.3.4", context.DnsEndPoint.Port);
    
    var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) { NoDelay = true };
    await socket.ConnectAsync(endPoint, cancellationToken);
    return new NetworkStream(socket, ownsSocket: true);
}
```

The request is made to 1.2.3.4 (or whatever IP you specify), but everything above the level of the TCP socket itself, including TLS, the `Host` header, etc, is still set to `example.com`, meaning that you shouldn't get certificate errors.

Comment: Thank you it's perfect